# Detecting if someone clicks "enter"

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to detect if someone clicks "enter" while entering a password.
I have a button that does this, but how would I do this with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

I've tried:

```
    If Keys.Enter = True And TextBox1.Text = "Password" Then
        MsgBox("Correct Password. Logging in.")
        LoginBox.Show() 
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    Else
    End If
  End Sub
```

The "Password" is what they need to enter, and LoginBox.Show is just a different part of the program.

Thanks!

Comment: What UI framework are you using? WinForms? WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the KeyDown event of the Textbox:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    ' // code...
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 'KeyCode' is not a member 'System.EventArgs' is what I get everytime I use e.KeyCode

Comment: @user2923747 Sounds like you use using the EventArgs from your button's click event.  That's not what my code is showing.  You have to use the KeyDown event of the TextBox where you want to detect that Enter key.

Comment: How would I make it if you click "F5" for the whole program. I want doing "F5" close the program and reopen (refresh). I tried LoginBox_Load (and) Handles LoginBox_KeyDown and such.

Comment: @user2923747 That's a separate question.  Click on the "Ask Question" link at the top.  That's really how Stack Overflow works.